# Wordpress accordion menu will not expand on click

Tags: php, jquery, html, css, wordpress

I just tried to follow this guide to implement an accordion menu in Wordpress.

http://cssmenumaker.com/blog/wordpress-accordion-menu-tutorial

My test site here: http://testsite2.seyoum.net/

If I follow the guide exactly as it says, WP is able to print the menu and I can see that the css styles is applied. The problem is that `li` groups will not expand when they are clicked (which is sort of the main point here). I am not sure if this is because the .js is not working or if there is something else.

I thought that maybe I had conflicting CSS from before so I made a new wordpress theme with _s, deleted all css styles (so that only the CSS from the accordion menu) was applied, but I still got the same problem. The menu is there. It just does not expand on click.

So what can be causing this?

**script.js:**

```
( function( $ ) {
$( document ).ready(function() {
$('#cssmenu li.has-sub>a').on('click', function(){
        $(this).removeAttr('href');
        var element = $(this).parent('li');
        if (element.hasClass('open')) {
            element.removeClass('open');
            element.find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.find('ul').slideUp();
        }
        else {
            element.addClass('open');
            element.children('ul').slideDown();
            element.siblings('li').children('ul').slideUp();
            element.siblings('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('li').removeClass('open');
            element.siblings('li').find('ul').slideUp();
        }
    });

    $('#cssmenu>ul>li.has-sub>a').append('<span class="holder"></span>');

    (function getColor() {
        var r, g, b;
        var textColor = $('#cssmenu').css('color');
        textColor = textColor.slice(4);
        r = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
        textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
        g = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(','));
        textColor = textColor.slice(textColor.indexOf(' ') + 1);
        b = textColor.slice(0, textColor.indexOf(')'));
        var l = rgbToHsl(r, g, b);
        if (l > 0.7) {
            $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
            $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(0, 0, 0, .35)');
        }
        else
        {
            $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a').css('text-shadow', '0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
            $('#cssmenu>ul>li>a>span').css('border-color', 'rgba(255, 255, 255, .35)');
        }
    })();

    function rgbToHsl(r, g, b) {
        r /= 255, g /= 255, b /= 255;
        var max = Math.max(r, g, b), min = Math.min(r, g, b);
        var h, s, l = (max + min) / 2;

        if(max == min){
            h = s = 0;
        }
        else {
            var d = max - min;
            s = l > 0.5 ? d / (2 - max - min) : d / (max + min);
            switch(max){
                case r: h = (g - b) / d + (g < b ? 6 : 0); break;
                case g: h = (b - r) / d + 2; break;
                case b: h = (r - g) / d + 4; break;
            }
            h /= 6;
        }
        return l;
    }
});
} )( jQuery );
```

**Rendered HTML:**

```
<div id="cssmenu" class="menu-accordion-menu-test-container"><ul id="menu-accordion-menu-test" class="menu"><li id="menu-item-1741" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Group 1</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-1743" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Sub Group 1</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li id="menu-item-1746" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-1747" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-1748" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-1744" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Sub Group 2</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li id="menu-item-1751" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Sub Group Level 3</span></a>
                    <ul>
                        <li id="menu-item-1749" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
                        <li id="menu-item-1750" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
                    </ul>
                </li>
                <li id="menu-item-1752" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-1753" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1754" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1755" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Group 2</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-1756" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1757" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1758" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Group 3</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-1759" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1760" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
<li id="menu-item-1761" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Group 4</span></a>
    <ul>
        <li id="menu-item-1762" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom menu-item-has-children has-sub"><a href="#"><span>Sub Group 3</span></a>
            <ul>
                <li id="menu-item-1763" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
                <li id="menu-item-1764" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
            </ul>
        </li>
        <li id="menu-item-1765" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
        <li id="menu-item-1766" class="menu-item menu-item-type-custom menu-item-object-custom"><a href="#"><span>Image</span></a></li>
    </ul>
</li>
</ul></div>
```

**CSS:**

```
#cssmenu,
#cssmenu ul,
#cssmenu ul li,
#cssmenu ul li a {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  border: 0;
  list-style: none;
  line-height: 1;
  display: block;
  position: relative;
  -webkit-box-sizing: border-box;
  -moz-box-sizing: border-box;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}
#cssmenu {
  width: 200px;
  font-family: Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul {
  display: none;
}
.align-right {
  float: right;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a {
  padding: 15px 20px;
  border-left: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-right: 1px solid #1682ba;
  border-top: 1px solid #1682ba;
  cursor: pointer;
  z-index: 2;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: bold;
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #ffffff;
  text-shadow: 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.35);
  background: #36aae7;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  background: linear-gradient(#36aae7, #1fa0e4);
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #1fa0e4;
  background: -webkit-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -moz-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -o-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: -ms-linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
  background: linear-gradient(#1fa0e4, #1992d1);
}
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.15), 0 1px 1px rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.15);
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #1682ba;
}
.holder {
  width: 0;
  height: 0;
  position: absolute;
  top: 0;
  right: 0;
}
.holder::after,
.holder::before {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 6px;
  height: 6px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
.holder::after {
  top: 17px;
  border-top: 2px solid #ffffff;
  border-left: 2px solid #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > a:hover > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.active > a > span::after,
#cssmenu > ul > li.open > a > span::after {
  border-color: #eeeeee;
}
.holder::before {
  top: 18px;
  border-top: 2px solid;
  border-left: 2px solid;
  border-top-color: inherit;
  border-left-color: inherit;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li a {
  cursor: pointer;
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-left: 1px solid #32373e;
  border-right: 1px solid #32373e;
  padding: 10px 20px;
  z-index: 1;
  text-decoration: none;
  font-size: 13px;
  color: #eeeeee;
  background: #49505a;
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:hover > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a,
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a {
  background: #424852;
  color: #ffffff;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: none;
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li:first-child > a {
  box-shadow: inset 0 1px 0 rgba(255, 255, 255, 0.1);
}
#cssmenu ul ul ul li a {
  padding-left: 30px;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > a,
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.last.open > a {
  border-bottom: 1px solid #32373e;
}
#cssmenu > ul > li > ul > li.open:last-child > ul > li:last-child > a {
  border-bottom: 0;
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.has-sub > a::after {
  display: block;
  position: absolute;
  content: "";
  width: 5px;
  height: 5px;
  right: 20px;
  z-index: 10;
  top: 11.5px;
  border-top: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  border-left: 2px solid #eeeeee;
  -webkit-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -moz-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -ms-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  -o-transform: rotate(-135deg);
  transform: rotate(-135deg);
}
#cssmenu ul ul li.active > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li.open > a::after,
#cssmenu ul ul li > a:hover::after {
  border-color: #ffffff;
}
```

**From header.php**

```
<<?php 
                    wp_nav_menu(array(
                      'menu' => 'Accordion menu test',   // This will be different for you. 
                      'container_id' => 'cssmenu', 
                      'walker' => new CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker()
                      )); 
                      ?>
```

**From functions.php:**

```
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cssmenumaker_scripts_styles' );
function cssmenumaker_scripts_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'cssmenu-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/cssmenu/styles.css');
   wp_enqueue_script('cssmenu-scripts', get_template_directory_uri() . '/cssmenu/script.js');
}

class CSS_Menu_Maker_Walker extends Walker {

  var $db_fields = array( 'parent' => 'menu_item_parent', 'id' => 'db_id' );

  function start_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "\n$indent<ul>\n";
  }

  function end_lvl( &$output, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $indent = str_repeat("\t", $depth);
    $output .= "$indent</ul>\n";
  }

  function start_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array(), $id = 0 ) {

    global $wp_query;
    $indent = ( $depth ) ? str_repeat( "\t", $depth ) : '';
    $class_names = $value = ''; 
    $classes = empty( $item->classes ) ? array() : (array) $item->classes;

    /* Add active class */
    if(in_array('current-menu-item', $classes)) {
      $classes[] = 'active';
      unset($classes['current-menu-item']);
    }

    /* Check for children */
    $children = get_posts(array('post_type' => 'nav_menu_item', 'nopaging' => true, 'numberposts' => 1, 'meta_key' => '_menu_item_menu_item_parent', 'meta_value' => $item->ID));
    if (!empty($children)) {
      $classes[] = 'has-sub';
    }

    $class_names = join( ' ', apply_filters( 'nav_menu_css_class', array_filter( $classes ), $item, $args ) );
    $class_names = $class_names ? ' class="' . esc_attr( $class_names ) . '"' : '';

    $id = apply_filters( 'nav_menu_item_id', 'menu-item-'. $item->ID, $item, $args );
    $id = $id ? ' id="' . esc_attr( $id ) . '"' : '';

    $output .= $indent . '<li' . $id . $value . $class_names .'>';

    $attributes  = ! empty( $item->attr_title ) ? ' title="'  . esc_attr( $item->attr_title ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->target )     ? ' target="' . esc_attr( $item->target     ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->xfn )        ? ' rel="'    . esc_attr( $item->xfn        ) .'"' : '';
    $attributes .= ! empty( $item->url )        ? ' href="'   . esc_attr( $item->url        ) .'"' : '';

    $item_output = $args->before;
    $item_output .= '<a'. $attributes .'><span>';
    $item_output .= $args->link_before . apply_filters( 'the_title', $item->title, $item->ID ) . $args->link_after;
    $item_output .= '</span></a>';
    $item_output .= $args->after;

    $output .= apply_filters( 'walker_nav_menu_start_el', $item_output, $item, $depth, $args );
  }

  function end_el( &$output, $item, $depth = 0, $args = array() ) {
    $output .= "</li>\n";
  }
}
```

Comment: provide a link or make a js fiddle / codepen with the header html that is outputted, relevant css  (php code is not useful) and js. could be anything causing it...but you should look at the console for js errors first.

Comment: jquery is undefined, google how to enqueue it in wp and add your script as a dependancy.

Comment: Is this correct? `function load_js() {
 wp_register_script( 'script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/cssmenu/script.js', array('jquery'));
 wp_enque_script('script');
}`

Comment: no jquery is still not loaded, you've miss spelled enqueue....see the console (right click and inspect) in chrome to see if js errors are present on your webpage

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found a very helpful and detailed guide here: https://premium.wpmudev.org/blog/adding-jquery-scripts-wordpress/

The solution was easy:

```
// Add styles to the cssmenu
add_action('wp_enqueue_scripts', 'cssmenumaker_scripts_styles' );
function cssmenumaker_scripts_styles() {
   wp_enqueue_style( 'cssmenu-styles', get_template_directory_uri() . '/cssmenu/styles.css');
}

// Add script to the css menu
function css_menu_script() {
    wp_enqueue_script( 'css_menu_script', get_template_directory_uri() . '/cssmenu/script.js', array( 'jquery' ), '1.0.0', true );
}
add_action( 'wp_enqueue_scripts', 'css_menu_script' );
```